# How to create Azure DevOps wiki reports for sprints?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

Sprint 146 in Azure DevOps introduced the possibility to embed queries in the Wiki. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-146-update#embed-azure-boards-query-results-in-wiki

In the image shown in the post:
[image: wiki]

It shows that you can, probably, create reports for each sprint. I have already some queries that are used to retrieve same data (for example active bugs), but are based on the current iteration like this:

```
Work Item Type = Bug
AND State Not In Done
AND Iteration Path Under @CurrentIteration
```

But I'd like to have a report I can see in the wiki for each of the sprint (both past and future ones) I have in the backlog, so how can I achieve that (if there's a way)?

I thought I could create and duplicate the same query replacing @CurrentIteration with the one that I'm interested in, but we're hundreds of sprints in the way, so I cannot create 100 copies of the same query just to replace a parameter.

Is there a simple way to do it? Am I missing something?

Comment: `Is there a simple way to do it? Am I missing something?` Based on my knowledge, GroupBy is not supported in WIT query. It seems that we are not able to do that with one query. I recomment that you could give your feedback to [Azure Devops team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21)